# Hide two sets of rows separately

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel VBA with 2 buttons. When one is clicked certain rows are hidden and when the other one is clicked another selection of rows are hidden.

When I try to hide both sections of rows it gives me a run-time error 1004

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Rows("7:14")
        .Select
        .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    With Rows("16:24")
       .Select
       .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: No-repro, works fine. Still, [do not use Select](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683).

Comment: Name the fist cell of the row and use `Range("name").EntireRow.Hidden = ...`